# Convert JSON date format from yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy android

Tags: android

I am parsing JSON data from a site and the date is coming back as "2018-05-15" .  How can I convert it to "05-15-2018"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one field for input format and one for output format.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
String inputDateStr="2018-05-15";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(date);
```

`outputDateStr` is your desired output.